# Java - Select the maximum integers from sliding windows over an array

Tags: java, algorithm, array, tree, statistics

So I have the following algorithm. Given an array `A[0 ... n - 1]` and the window length `w`, compute all the windows `A[0 ... w - 1], A[1 ... w], ..., A[n - w, n - 1]`, and for each window, in order, compute the maximum integer in the window, storing it in a result array:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Main {

    private static final int[] EMPTY_INT_ARRAY = new int[0];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {7, 86, 19, 5, 79, 28, 56, 8, 46, 63, 98, 65, 99};
        int[] result = computeArrayWindowMaxima(array, 8);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
        System.out.println();

        array = new int[]{1, 100, 2, 100, 4, 5, 6, 7};
        result = computeArrayWindowMaxima(array, 4);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }

    public static int[] computeArrayWindowMaxima(int[] array, 
                                                 int windowLength) {

        Objects.requireNonNull(array, "The input array is null.");

        if (array.length == 0) {
            return EMPTY_INT_ARRAY;
        }

        // Let n = array.length, m = windowLength.
        windowLength = Math.min(windowLength, array.length);
        int[] result = new int[array.length - windowLength + 1];
        OrderStatisticTree<Integer> tree = new OrderStatisticTree<>();
        Map<Integer, Integer> counterMap = new HashMap<>();

        // Initialize the tree. Runs in O(m log m):
        for (int i = 0; i < windowLength; ++i) {
            tree.add(array[i]);
            counterMap.put(array[i],
                           counterMap.getOrDefault(array[i], 0) + 1);
        }

        // Runs in O((n - m) log m).
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length - 1; ++i) {
            // Store tree window maximum. Runs in O(log m).
            result[i] = tree.get(tree.size() - 1);

            // Remove the int right before the current window. Runs in
            // O(log m).
            if (counterMap.getOrDefault(array[i], 0) < 2) {
                counterMap.remove(array[i]);
                tree.remove(array[i]);
            } else {
                counterMap.put(array[i], counterMap.get(array[i]) - 1);
            }

            // Add the int right after the current window. Runs in O(log m).
            tree.add(array[windowLength + i]);
            counterMap.put(array[windowLength + i],
                           counterMap.getOrDefault(
                                   array[windowLength],
                                   0)
                           + 1);
        }

        result[result.length - 1] = tree.get(tree.size() - 1);
        // Finally, we have O(m \log m) + O((n - m) log m) = O(n log m).
        return result;
    }
}
```

In the above procedure, `tree` [1] holds the current window and the `counterMap` is used to count the number of times each `int` in the window occurs in that window. We need `counterMap` since it is possible that multiple maximum `ìnt`s belong to a window and removing one will "remove all duplicates", so to say.

**Critique request**

Now, what do you think? As always, tell me whatever comes to mind.

[1] [Order statistic tree.](https://github.com/coderodde/OrderStatisticTree/blob/master/src/main/java/net/coderodde/util/OrderStatisticTree.java)

Comment: There is at least one slick O(n) algorithm. Looking for a collection that supports `add(key)`, `remove(key)` & `maxKey()` fast is barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @greybeard https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sliding-window-maximum-maximum-of-all-subarrays-of-size-k/amp/. 
And all of a sudden, the problem turned out to be boring.

Comment: I guess it's interesting as an interview question: *If* the interviewee doesn't seem to remember problem&solution, s/he's bound to fall into the PQ trap. The interesting part is the reaction confronted with the interviewer's asking for/asserting there *is* a straightforward O(n) solution.

Comment: @greybeard Beyond my level.

Answer (score 1):

There may be avoidable overhead in finding the same key in a Map twice in a row, OTOH, an "industrial strength" `Map` implementation might cache the last entry returned.
To avoid it in `map.put(key, map.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1);` use a modifiable Number like java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger.
Or `map.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum)`.

Not using `rank(x)`/`OrderStatisticTree.indexOf(x)` and only `index(0)`/`tree.get(tree.size() - 1)`, you don't need an order statistic tree in `computeArrayWindowMaxima()`,  the NavigableMultiSet (Bag) the JRE doesn't quite provide should do.
Creating a decorator turning a `java.util.Map<T, tally>` into a "Bag"
- ordered if the map passed into the constructor is - was reusable and improved readability&robustness of "Bag handling" as in `computeArrayWindowMaxima()`.

---

Don't repeat printing an array:

```
/** Prints an array of integers to <code>out</code>. */
void printArray(PrintStream out, int[] values) // ah, Java primitive arrays
{
    out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
}
/** Prints an array of integers to the standard output stream. */
void printArray(int[] values) { printArray(System.out, values); }
```

Just for the habit, specify the initial capacity:
`counterMap = new HashMap<>(windowLength);`

---

If pressed for time, I might forego a decent stab at `NavigableMultiSet` and use

```
    NavigableSet<Integer> pq = new TreeSet<Integer>() { // encode array value&index
            final int base = array.length;
            /** encodes array value (more significant)&index */
            int encode(int elementIndex) {
                return array[elementIndex] * base + elementIndex;
            }
            // @Override
            public boolean add(Integer elementIndex) {
                return super.add(encode(elementIndex));
            }
            // @Override
            public boolean remove(Integer elementIndex) {
                return super.remove(encode(elementIndex));
            }
            // @Override
            public Integer last() {
                return super.last()/base;
            }
        };
```

- smells.